# How to access the MSIL code of compiled .NET assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, intermediate-code

[VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) and [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) (and other language) compilers generate MSIL code. How can I see that code?

What is there in that file? Where does that file reside and how can I access that?

Second question:

How do I compile a C# program from the `cmd` prompt and how do I check each and every file created using that compiler?

Comment: I think you need to clear up your question - the CLR is an abstract concept, and doesn't *generate* MSIL. What code are you trying to see?

Comment: I have read that  .Net Compactible language like VB.Net or C# are compiles into Miceosoft Intermediate Language.

Comment: Yes, okay, that is true. But that's about the VB and C# compilers. The CLR is about a runtime environment in which .NET executables run.

Comment: That means C# and VB.Net compiler generates MSIL not the CLR

Comment: your vote to this may help me get more answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed DLLs and EXEs are in MSIL.

You can see the MSIL using [ildasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx).

Comment: For the benefit of searchers, this tool will be held somewhere like C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools. The reference in this post has some samples at the bottom which are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The Ildasm.exe tool is installed <strike>with the framework</strike> along with VS. You can find it in the `<Program Files>\Microsoft SDKs` folder.

It opens .EXE and .DLL files.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a decompiler, such as Telerik's JustDecompile (free). With it you can open any .NET executable or DLL and examine the generated MSIL (in the language of your choice).

http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx